# In C language, given a file dirctory, how to use fopen to read the file?

Tags: c, file

My code is something like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXFILENAMESIZE 100

int main(){
    char file_name[MAXFILENAMESIZE];
    scanf("%s", file_name);
    printf("%s\n", file_name);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if(!fp){
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file reading\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

My input is something like below:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\user_missions.csv
```

I expect my executable being able to find the file, yet my file pointer is always null.

I am pretty sure that I do have the file in the directory.

Since I just started to learn programming, if my question is not clear enough, please remind me to improve it.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like it should work if that's the correct pathname.

Comment: Try using `perror()` to print the error message when `fopen()` fails.

Comment: Did you try another file, which you know for sure to exist?

Comment: Oh I found the problem.
It was because I should not use '\' in the path name.
Instead, I should use '/'.